# Nginx redirect config issue

Tags: nginx, openshift, bitnami

I have nginx  bitnami container deployed in Openshift that serves my application. The issue that I am facing is that the redirect is not working. In the logs, there are no indications that the request is caught by a `proxy_pass` location block.

So. the idea is that a request to `app.com/backend1/api/something` should be forwarded to `service1.com/backend1/api/something`. The same goes for service2.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    upstream service1 {
      server service1.com;
    }

    upstream service2 {
      server service2.com;
    }

    server {
      listen 8443 ssl;
      listen [::]:8443 http2 ssl;

      server_name app.com;

      error_log  /opt/bitnami/nginx/error.log  debug;


      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
      ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
      ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_session_timeout 10m;
      keepalive_timeout   70;

      include /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/mime.types;

      root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html;

      location ~ ^/backend1/api/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass https://service1/backend1/api/$1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }

      location ~ ^/backend2/api/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass https://service2/backend2/api/$1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }

      location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
      }

    }
}
```

I have also tried moving the order of the `location` blocks, as well as moving the `root` directive, but without success.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: If using OpenShift, why not just create two routes with a ``path`` matching the sub URL prefix and associate the routes with the different services? You don't need to have a separate internal nginx instance, the existing routing mechanism can already split traffic based on sub URL path.

Comment: I have thought about that, but my apps are separated into different namespaces, and the router does not allow me to have the same domain into different namespaces. So `app.com/path1` into one namespaces and `app.com/path2` into different namespace is not allowed.

Comment: If you have no admin control over the cluster, yes you would have that restriction. If you have full control over the cluster and it isn't shared with other users you don't trust, you can relax the restriction. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/architecture/networking/routes.html#disable-namespace-ownership-check

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have these restrictions and probably nginx will be my only savior. Still stuck with the config though...

Comment: Even if you use nginx, depending on how the cluster is setup, you may need to setup a pod network between projects to allow pods in one to access services in another. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/admin_guide/managing_networking.html So still potentially need admin access.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, but these proxies should be considered as pointing to external services (looking at them like they are not on the same Openshift cluster).